# gpg will not let me change my passphrase

Tags: gpg

I want to change my gpg passphrase so I do

```
tweedleburg:~/.gnupg # gpg --list-secret-keys
/root/.gnupg/secring.gpg
------------------------
sec   1024D/43E855BB 2008-02-03
uid                  Thorsten Staerk <Thorsten@Staerk.de>
ssb   2048g/2220D430 2008-02-03
```

So I do have a secret key and a user id. But gpg is not accepting it:

```
tweedleburg:~/.gnupg # gpg --passwd
gpg (GnuPG) 2.0.26; Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

usage: gpg [options] --passwd <user-id>
tweedleburg:~/.gnupg # gpg --passwd Thorsten@Staerk.de
gpg (GnuPG) 2.0.26; Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

gpg: error changing the passphrase for `Thorsten@Staerk.de': No secret key
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I mean, no one tells you this is a user ID. Anyway, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the numeric id:

```
gpg --passwd 43E855BB
```